# Angular2 routing v3.0.0 with deeply nested routes

Tags: angularjs, angular, routes, router

right now migrating from router v2 to v3 (feels like a deja vu). The routing configuration is now decoupled from the components again. It overthrows the logic I considered quite sensible. They have introduced a `children` property in the `RouterConfig` which gives me headache. Assume an application with many routes similar to this

```
/club/123/member/98/tasklist/921/edit
```

The route was spread over the following components with the following @Routes decorators

```
@Routes([{path: '/club/:id', component: DelegateClubComponent}])
export class MainApp {...}

@Routes([{path: 'user/:id', component: DelegateUserComponent}])
export class DelegateClubComponent {...}

@Routes([{path: 'tasklist/:id', component: DelegateTaskListComponent}])
export class DelegateUserComponent {...}

@Routes([{path: 'edit', component: EditTaskListComponent}])
export class DelegateTaskListComponent {...}
```

Each of the `DelegateXComponents` were responsible for resolving the respective document and making it available in a `Service` the other components get injected. Moreoever, all of the `DelegateXComponents` rendered a little template with some data of the documents they were in charge of.

How is this done with router v3 ? It makes no sense to map the entire tree in a nested `RouterConfig` with 5 levels of `children`. On the other hand, do separate `RouterConfig`s work at all?

```
export const clubRoute: RouterConfig = [
  { path: 'club/:id', component: DelegateClubComponent }];

export const userRoute: RouterConfig = [
  { path: 'user/:id', component: DelegateUserComponent }];
```

As long as there is no magic happening behind the scenes, how would the router know that the `userRoute` should be considered as a child route for `clubRoute`.

Confused greetings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define configs in the same files as the components and then just combine them to a complete tree before passing it to the router.

```
import {childRoutes} from './child.component'

export const clubRoute: RouterConfig = [
  { path: 'club/:id', component: DelegateClubComponent, children: childRoutes }];
```

Comment: Thx. Seems like a reasonable solution. Do you have an idea why the component-related routing as of v2 was abandoned?

Comment: It caused troubles with lazy loading where the component needed to be loaded in order to figure out if it can be activated (something along these lines - don't know exactly).